# Best way to add a group count to a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm learning Python and am working with the Titanic dataset to learn. More than one passenger is travelling on a ticket and I'd like to add a feature of the groupsize on a row-level so with the passenger.

I use this code:

```
tickets = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticket', 'groupsize'])
tickets['groupsize'] = titanic['ticket'].value_counts()
tickets['ticket'] = tickets.index
newTitanic = pd.merge(titanic, tickets, how= 'left', on = 'ticket')
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please share your data as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map instead of groupby,

```
df['groupsize'] = df['ticket'].map(df['ticket'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Wow. So nice. Thank you.

Comment: @MacMesser, do accept the most helpful answer. It helps in closing the thread

Answer (score 0):

```py
titanic['groupsize'] = titanic.groupby('ticket')['PassengerID'].count().reset_index()['PassengerID']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
titanic['groupsize'] = titanic.groupby('Ticket').Ticket.transform('value_counts')
```

In the given situation you'd normally use the following to get the number of names per ticket:

```
titanic['groupsize'] = titanic.groupby('Ticket').Name.transform('count')
```

[Here](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) is a detailed explanation of how `transform` with `groupby` works.

Comment: Thanks. Was working on something else tonight. Whish I new this earlier!

Comment: Glad to have helped you. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer and/or [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answers that solved your problem. This helps keep this site useful and ensures that other users with similar questions can quickly find an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will simplify things but not sure it is more efficient

```
for value in titanic['Ticket'].unique():
    titanic.loc[titanic['Ticket'] == value, 'groupSize'] = titanic['Ticket'].value_counts()[value]
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. Below I got some very nice solutions.